# SQL Server Function to get count of certain view rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I need a script (SQL server Function) to get the count of certain view rows .
I have a code for a table like this :

```
ALTER FUNCTION  [dbo].[COUNT_ROWS_TABLE](@TABLE_NAME NVARCHAR(100))
 RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ROW_COUNT INT
SELECT @ROW_COUNT = SUM(b.rows) 
FROM SYS.tables a INNER JOIN sys.partitions b ON b.OBJECT_ID = a.OBJECT_ID
WHERE a.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND b.index_id IN (1,0)
        and a.name=@TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY a.name

RETURN @ROW_COUNT
END
```

I need one for Views

Comment: Views don't store any data, therefore sys.partitions has no data for such objects. Can you show us any attempts to resolve your problem? It looks like you're waiting that someone just come and do everything for you.

Comment: Did you see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37581745/list-row-count-of-each-view-and-table ? It looks like there is a solution of your problem.

Comment: I need this for certain views , I'll send the view name as a parameter

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourViewHere`. You cannot use `sys.partitions` unless it's an indexed view, in which case your above query will work, just replace `sys.tables` with `sys.views`